# nuodb sql syntaxe validator

Tags: sql, nuodb

I need an online nuodb sql query syntax validator. I searched online but didn't find anything good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any online tool.  If you have an existing nuodb database you can easily verify the syntax with nuosql on linux or mac with some simple scripting.

```
statement=[your sql statement]
echo "diagnose $statement" | nuosql --user username --password password --nosemicolon <dbname>
```